# Ruby on rails - Multiple administrator type on activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, cancancan

Currently, I have a administrator on activeadmin that can do everything. But, I want to have an other level of administrator that can do everything except adding/removing/editing new administrators. Do you have a Idea of a simple way to archieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own Authorization adapter and use them in views:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do

  index do
    column :title
    column '' do |post|
      link_to 'Edit', admin_post_path(post) if authorized? :update, post
    end
  end

end
```

Doc reference: https://activeadmin.info/13-authorization-adapter.html